# React : Call a function from inside render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have referred to couple of similar questions, but I have a situation little different.

[Call a React Function from inside Render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956540/call-a-react-function-from-inside-render)

[How to Call a Function inside a Render in React/Jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298136/how-to-call-a-function-inside-a-render-in-react-jsx)

[React: Cant call a function inside child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502165/react-cant-call-a-function-inside-child-component)

```js
export default class CodeEditor extends React.Component {

  appendAssets(asset) {
    console.log(asset)
    this.refs.editor.editor.insert(`player.asset('${asset}')`)
    this.refs.editor.editor.focus()
  }


  render() {
    function sequenceHierarchy (data, outputArray) {
      level++
      data.forEach(function (asset){
        outputArray.push(<li className={`level_${level}`}><button onClick={_ => this.appendAssets(asset.name)}>{asset.name}</button></li>)
        if(asset.children.length) {
          sequenceHierarchy(asset.children, outputArray)
        }
      })
      level--
    }
  }

}
```

So the `onClick` of button inside `sequenceHierarchy` function has to call `appendAssets`. Of course since `this` wouldn't be able to call it as it is not the part of this component, I also tried with just `appendAssets(asset.name)`, still it gives a error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: appendAssets is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly advise you to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/4248342) for understanding `this` keyword and its behaviors inside function.

Quoting from the linked answer:

> this (aka "the context") is a special keyword inside each function and **its value only depends on how the function was called**, not how/when/where it was defined. It is not affected by lexical scope, like other variables.

(Please read whole linked answer before proceeding further)

You can either set a reference to the variable which refers to correct `this`. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j9f5kr1n/)

```
let that = this; // assign this reference to variable that.
function sequenceHierarchy (data, outputArray) {
   data.forEach((item) => {
        outputArray.push(
          <li>
            <button onClick={that.appendAssets.bind(this, item)}>
               Append {item}
             </button>
          </li>
      );            
   })
}
```

or

You can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method to set correct `this`, while invoking `sequenceHierarchy` function as follows. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jtf0h70b/)

```
{sequenceHierarchy.bind(this, (['1', '2', '3'], []))}
```

or

You can use [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to invoke `sequenceHierarchy` function like this.

```
{() => {sequenceHierarchy(['1', '2', '3'], [])}}
```

All above methods will work fine.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks Hardik. That helped me out.

Comment: Glad it helped :)